# Looping through values in file data

Tags: python, csv, file

Write   a   script high_scores.py that will read    in  a   CSV file    of users' scores    and display the
highest score   for each    person. The file    you will read   in  is  named   scores.csv. You should  store   the high    scores  as  values
in  a   dictionary  with    the associated  names   as  dictionary  keys. This  way,    as  you read    in
each    row of data, if the name    already has a   score   associated  with    it in   the dictionary, you
can compare these   two scores  and decide  whether or not to   replace the "current" high
score   in  the dictionary.
Use the     sorted()     function   on  the dictionary's    keys    in  order to    display an  ordered list of
high    scores, which   should  match   this    output:

```
Empiro  23
L33tH4x 42
LLCoolDave  27
MaxxT   25
Misha46 25
O_O 22
johnsmith   30
red 12
tom123  26
```

scores.csv :

```
LLCoolDave,23
LLCoolDave,27
red,12
LLCoolDave,26
tom123,26
O_O,7
Misha46,24
O_O,14
Empiro,18
Empiro,18
MaxxT,25
L33tH4x,42
Misha46,25
johnsmith,30
Empiro,23
O_O,22
MaxxT,25
Misha46,24
```

I stumbled on how to check if i need to replace score of certain name

```
import csv
dic = {}
with open("scores.csv", "r") as my_file:
     my_file_reader = csv.reader(my_file)
     for i in my_file_reader:
         dic[i[0]] = i[1]
```

Answer (score 2):

If you run your code on the csv, you'll see that LLCoolDave's score is 26 instead of 27. This is because you update your dictionary every time a new entry is seen, and effectively, you're keeping the most recent scores -- not the highest. To fix this, you can try something like:

```
import csv
dic = {}
with open("scores.csv", "r") as my_file:
     my_file_reader = csv.reader(my_file)
     for row in my_file_reader:
        if row[0] in dic:
            dic[row[0]] = max(dic[row[0]], row[1])
        else:
            dic[row[0]] = row[1]
print(dic)
```

Essentially, we are first checking whether an entry exists for the current user. If yes, his best score is the maximum of the new score and the previous best score. Otherwise, his best score is just whatever the new score is.